# Using Mapnik's OGR plugin for Oracle Spatial Database

Tags: ogr, mapnik, oracle-spatial

Mapnik wiki page of OGR plugin says that I can use the plugin for MSSQL server in the following manner:

```
<Layer name="mssql" srs="+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84">
    <StyleName>mssql_style</StyleName>
    <Datasource>
        <!-- mssql database must contain geometry_columns and spatial_ref_sys metadata tables-->
        <Parameter name="type">ogr</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="string">MSSQL:server=localhost;database=gis;trusted_connection=yes</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="layer_by_sql">SELECT * FROM dbo.planet_osm_line</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="extent">-180,-90,180,89.99</Parameter>
    </Datasource>
</Layer>
```

I want to use it for Oracle Spatial Database. How should I modify the parameter with name = "string" in the XML so that I can?

Also, do I need to install any additional software and make any configurations on my machine so that I can connect to the database?

By the way, the database is not on my localhost but in a remote location.

Comment: It is documented here http://www.gdal.org/drv_oci.html, I suppose that you must use this string `OCI:userid/password@database_instance:table,table`. Do you have OCI driver compiled into your GDAL? You can check it from command line with `ogrinfo --formats` and you should see `OCI -vector- (rw+): Oracle Spatial`.

Comment: OCI driver is indeed not compiled into my GDAL. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't know. It is worth another question and it may belong rather to stackoverflow.